# Flutter nested lists - custom CheckBox

Tags: flutter, dart, nested-lists

I'm really confused about this situation, I'm trying to build this app just like in the image below, the app is all about having a list of ExpansionTiles inside each one there is a list of items, each item has it's own three checkboxes[true, false, avoid], and also the ExpansionTile it self has it's own three checkboxes that can be clicked globally, instead of selecting them one by one,what I need is to get to the best solution to implement this, to know which item in which list were selected and to give a result depending on it, I'm really confused and tried many ways, many models for data, but failed, any help will be really app, I'd be more than glad with any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clxVg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a controlled widget for the three checkboxes, passing parameters for `onChange` and `value` (Value can be determined using an `enum`)

Then I'd reuse that widget everywhere I need

Then I'd go for an expansible widget that contains the list (Column widget maybe?)

Try to handle as many states as possible, having controlled widgets
Or if you're using BloC you can easily implement your core logic with this UI:)

Comment: Thank you, can you send me your WhatsApp number or a way to chat?
I tried to message you on Twitter, but it's unavailable

Comment: What's your twitter user? I'll ping you there hahaha
I can send you my telegram too

Comment: Just followed you on twitter, check it out and ping me a message